# Array to Object JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array like this:

```
[{
    mercado: "CAM",
    region: "CAM Uno",
    Cliente: "Jonhy"
}, {
    mercado: "CAM",
    region: "CAM Uno",
    Cliente: "Alex"
}, {
    mercado: "CAM",
    region: "CAM Dos",
    Cliente: "Jullian"
}, {
    mercado: "NAM",
    region: "OCI",
    Cliente: "Pascal"
}, {
    mercado: "NAM",
    region: "FLI",
    Cliente: "Sofia"
}, {
    mercado: "NAM",
    region: "FLI",
    Cliente: "Priya"
}];
```

I want an object like as:

```
[{
    mercado: "CAM",
    region: [{
        nombre: "CAM Uno",
        Cliente: ["Jonhy", "Alex"]
    }, {
        nombre: "CAM Dos",
        Cliente: ["Jullian"]
    }]
}, {
    mercado: "NAM",
    region: [{
        nombre: "OCI",
        Cliente: ["Pascal"]
    }, {
        nombre: "FLI",
        Cliente: ["Sofia", "Priya"]
    }]
}];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I mean, the answer to your question is yes. I assume you're also looking for implementation help?

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes. As for implementing it, what have you tried?

Comment: How is the original object being created? I assume it is being handed off to you somehow (via PHP or some other way)? Otherwise, just reorganize it the way you want it. Also, the above is not valid JSON as it needs to have double quotation marks around keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object for refrence to the inserted items in the result set.

```js
var data = [{ mercado: "CAM", region: "CAM Uno", Cliente: "Jonhy" }, { mercado: "CAM", region: "CAM Uno", Cliente: "Alex" }, { mercado: "CAM", region: "CAM Dos", Cliente: "Jullian" }, { mercado: "NAM", region: "OCI", Cliente: "Pascal" }, { mercado: "NAM", region: "FLI", Cliente: "Sofia" }, { mercado: "NAM", region: "FLI", Cliente: "Priya" }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = { mercado: a.mercado, region: [] };
    if (!this[a.mercado]) {
        this[a.mercado] = { region: o.region, };
        grouped.push(o);
    }
    if (!this[a.mercado][a.region]) {
        this[a.mercado][a.region] = { nombre: a.region, Cliente: [] };
        this[a.mercado].region.push(this[a.mercado][a.region]);
    }
    this[a.mercado][a.region].Cliente.push(a.Cliente);
}, Object.create(null));
  
console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Again you posting better answers than mine.